# Is it normal for Phantom on Localnet to fail to simulate everything?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, phantom, react, phantom-wallet

Every transaction I make on localhost fails to simulate. Is this expected anytime using Phantom on Localnet? New to Solana dev, so maybe I am dumb...

[image]

- I am using anchor
- I am using `@coral-xyz/anchor` client side.

It is the `interact` function exported from the below hook I am calling. Again, the transactino completes as expected, but really confused how to get the txn to simulate successfully in Phantom on Localnet.

```
import {
  useConnection,
  useAnchorWallet,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { AnchorPgm, IDL } from '@/idl/anchor_pgm';
import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const generateTxnUrl = (sig: string) => {
  switch (import.meta.env.MODE) {
    case 'development':
      return `https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${sig}?cluster=custom`;
    case 'production':
      return `https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${sig}?cluster=devnet`;
    default:
      return `https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${sig}`;
  }
};

const programId = new PublicKey(
  import.meta.env.VITE_PROGRAM_ID,
);

const useProgram = () => {
  const [program, setProgram] =
    useState<anchor.Program<AnchorPgm>>();
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const wallet = useAnchorWallet();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!wallet || !connection) return;

    const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(
      connection,
      wallet,
      {},
    );
    anchor.setProvider(provider);
    const program = new anchor.Program(
      IDL as anchor.Idl,
      programId,
    ) as unknown as anchor.Program<AnchorPgm>;
    setProgram(program);
  }, [wallet, connection]);

  const interact = async () => {
    if (!program || !wallet)
      throw new Error('Pgram not initted');

    const pdaAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    // mock data
    const data = new anchor.BN(1);

    const txn = await program.methods
      .initialize(data)
      .accounts({
        newAccount: pdaAccount.publicKey,
        signer: wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .signers([pdaAccount])
      .rpc();

    const txnUrl = generateTxnUrl(txn);
    console.log('txnUrl', txnUrl);
  };

  return { interact };
};

export default useProgram;
```

Maybe related, but also every balance is stuck in "loading" state in phantom when on `Localnet`.

I have all solana CLI tooling installed and test validator is running.
FWIW, the transaction completes and I can view it in the "custom" explorer on localhost.
Maybe I am missing some further configuration in Phantom or

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://docs.phantom.app/resources/faq#why-cant-i-access-phantom-on-my-website answers your question -- localhost likely has very limited support in general

Comment: Word. This is helpful. Thanks so much!